# Hardware module with multiple interrupt flag (C)

Tags: c, embedded, system, interrupt

We are currently using an embedded microcontroller (i.MX 7Dual Processors). With this processor, we use a module called Flextimer (FTM). This module execute two tasks for us :

1. 16-bit timer
2. Pulse detection

The pulse detection is detected through an interrupt which is then handle in the ISR. At the same time, the module FTM is increasing the timer. Surely the timer will overflow, so the processor also have an interrupt to notify the overflow. Since it's the same module the same ISR is called... The timer is use to compute the number of pulse detected. Unfortunately, sometime the overflow happen at the same time we are reading the timer value, while we are still computing the pulse detection. The consequence is the reading of a small value of the timer without the possibility to be flagged for the overflow.

The 16-bit timer is limitative since it triggers often, but we don't have any other choice. I tried to find a way to handle the two flags, but can't figured it out. Is there in C anyway to handle two flags?

Also, since this processor doesn't handle interrupt priority, I'm not sure the implementation of an another timer would actually solve the problem. Is the only solution is a longer timer to prevent frequent overflow?

Comment: Are there not any interrupt flags that are set in the case when both interrupts happen?  That is usually how this is handled - system set IF flag and then calls base ISR.  Base ISR checks flags and runs each ISR as needed, with interrupts enabled so that no info is lost.  I am also curious if you are disabling interrupts when you handle them or if you allow nested interrupts (another possible way to handle this.)  Disabled interrupts of course cause a loss of data on bad timing.

Comment: A "hack" would be to read the timer and the beginning and end of your ISR.  If the timer is lower at the end than at the beginning, it rolled over and you missed an interrupt so recover.  Not full-proof at all, but a stop gap.

Comment: You might like to show us a [example], and optimally [edit] your question with a link to the microcontroller's data sheet / manual.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.